# Are you allowed to get a haircut on Motzei Shabbos?

Tags: hair, motzei-shabbos, halacha

Is there anything wrong with getting a haircut on Motzei Shabbos (Saturday night)?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason it is said that its best not to get a haircut on Motzei Shabbos is because of the following: it is a nice thing to get a haircut on Friday to honor the approaching shabbos. If you wait till Motzei shabbos, it is embarrasing to shabbos because you didn't do it before and you are doing it right after. Therefore, it is probably better to wait until Sunday.

This would probably apply to shaving as well.

Comment: This explanation is given [here](http://www.moreshet.co.il/web/shut/shut2.asp?id=63659)

Answer (score 2):

In a discussion about whether cutting hair on Friday when Rosh Chodesh Sivan is on Sunday is similar to when Lag Baomer is on Sunday, [R. Shlomo Kluger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Kluger) makes the following point:

**Chochmat Shlomo O.C. 493:2**

> ובפרט דבזיון הוא שעל שבת לא יגלח וביום אחד אחר השבת יגלח
>
> And particularly because it is disgraceful that for Shabbat he didn’t shave but on Sunday after Shabbat he did shave.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Chaim Kanievsky in Sefer Leket Shalos Hameetzuyos vol 3 page 29 writes that it is not proper . The footnote brings a small proof from the Rama 493:2

Comment: I'm not seeing the proof from 493:2.

Comment: Same here,but that's what the footnote says ,and I have heard ppl say this is a mekor,I dont see it in the words

Comment: See Alex's answer

Comment: Still dont see it in Rama

Answer (score -5):

Yes, you are allowed. Jewish people are meant to look religious and tznious, so it is okay to get haircuts night and day.

Comment: Even on Shabbos?

Comment: @double aa, maybe he means Sunday?

Comment: @SethJ Maybe he means on Tuesday too.

Comment: Rabbi Eliezer Hertz, welcome to Mi Yodeya! You could make your answer much more valuable by backing it up with a source and specifying exactly what you mean, per the above comments.